# Are Steiner points always the vertex in Delaunay triangulation?

Tags: computational-geometry, triangulation

I'm reading up about [Steiner point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_point_(triangle)), and it's quite unclear whether I can use Steiner points to form the vertexes in the Delaunay triangulation. The wiki entry above doesn't seem to be clear on this.

So if I pick some points inside a polygon as Steiner points and I triangulate it via Delaunay triangulation, are those points *guaranteed* to end up as vertexes of the triangulation?

Answer (score 0):

We can formulate many geometric optimization problems with or without [Steiner points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_point_(computational_geometry)), and these points are simply *additional* points, which don't exist in the input data. This term appeared in Computational Geometry because of the [Steiner tree problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem), where additional points allowed us to get a shorter spanning tree for a plane point set.

So, yes, if you add Steiner points inside a polygon, you'll probably get a better triangulation, and *all these additional points will be vertices in this triangulation* (Delaunay or not). Questions are:

1. How to measure a quality of triangulation?
2. How many additional points are needed?
3. Where to place these additional points?

If you still need to deal with these questions please take a look at [this](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/%7Et-asano/papers/OptimalTriangulation.pdf) paper.